# jquery unbind event from multiple input fields in one go

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, unbind

I have requirement where I need to track changes to input fields in a particular div and trigger an event if something is changed.

I am using following code to accomplish that

```
                $('div.dc2-content:eq(1) input:not([aria-readonly])').each(function(){
                    var $elem = $(this);
                    $elem.data("oldval",$elem.val());
                    $elem.on("change",{ctx:this},setItemStatus);
                });
```

This is working fine but the second part of the requirement is that the event should be triggered only once. Which means that

1. When the first fields is changed trigger the event.
2. Then unbind the change from all the input fields

For this part I wrote following function

```
        function setItemStatus(event){
            var $el = $(this);
            if($el.val() != $el.data("oldval")){
                console.log("Invoke Update Method");
                //unbind the events so that it doesn't trigger the update twice.
                $('div.dc2-content:eq(1) input:not([aria-readonly])').each(function(){
                    var $elm = $(this);
                    $elm.off("change");
                });
            }

        }
```

But even after this change event is not unbinded it still triggers if I make a change in any other field of the form.

I know I can put conditions to stop executing the code but I would like to unbind.

Comment: have u try .unbind()? instead of .off().

Comment: Yes, and it didn't work. The problem is that the selector in the function is not selecting any input tags. It never triggers the off code. I am using the same selector which is working fine in binding.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jquery's [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) method, instead of the `on`.

```
$('div.dc2-content:eq(1) input:not([aria-readonly])').each(function(){
  var $elem = $(this);
  $elem.data("oldval",$elem.val());
  $elem.one("change",{ctx:this},setItemStatus);
});
```

Then, you don't need to "off" the event anymore since that's what `one` method do.

Comment: But one means it will trigger once for every field. I need to basically restrict it to once per form.

Comment: Oh you're right, misunderstood the question. Try passing the attached function to the off method as well `$elm.off("change", setItemStatus);`

Comment: passing the method would cause this method to execute again. wouldn't it. The problem seems to be that in the function selector to select the inputs is not working. It never selects any input fields. Any idea why that would happen ???

Comment: Maybe it's your version of jQuery? I made a [codpen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tnqgv?editors=101) emulating your problem and it works. Try testing on your site.